# Your config/database.yml may not be written correctly. Please check it and fix any errors

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am trying to install redmine on a Ubuntu system and I believe it should be running correctly. But it seems to get stuck here:

```
Your config/database.yml may not be written correctly. Please check it and fix any errors.
Your database schema may be out of date or nonexistant. Please run rake db:migrate to ensure that the database schema is up-to-date.
The database server may not be running. Please check whether it's running, and start it if it isn't.
```

My database.yml is set up correctly, mysql is running and the credetionals are correct.

```
production:
adapter: mysql
database: myredminedb
host: localhost
username: redmine
password: password
encoding: utf8w
```

Its currently on http://track.hutber.com/ using a seperate vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/hutber.com/track.hutber.com
        ServerName track.hutber.com

    <Directory /var/www/hutber.com/track.hutber.com>
       Options FollowSymLinks
       RailsBaseURI /usr/share/redmine
       PassengerResolveSymlinksinDocumentRoot on               
       AllowOverride None
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am completely stumped. I'm a php guy myself...

Upon running rake db:migrate

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
(in /usr/share/redmine)
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/share/redmine/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /usr/share/redmine/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
Please install RDoc 2.4.2+ to generate documentation.
Character set 'utf8w' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
rake aborted!
Can't initialize character set utf8w (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Do you already indent 2 spaces for all lines below production: ?

Comment: what happens if you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: added the 2 spaces, indeed it changed something. See updated track. Also i ran rake, didn't look to good. I've obviously missed something in the install. Updating question

Comment: Updated response with rake db:migrate

Comment: Updated answer to deal with utf8 issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `rake db:migrate` from within the application root. That would be the directory with the file `Rakefile` in it. Not sure from the details of your question, but my guess would be you need to do this:

```
cd /var/www/hutber.com/track.hutber.com
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

**UPDATE**

And change your charset in `database.yml` to `utf8`. It currently is set to `utf8w`